# Refactoring if-else if chain in Java 8 style

Tags: java, java-8

I have a method with the following if-else-if chain:

```
        if(downstreamActual.getNumber() <= downstreamRecommended.getNumber()){
            downstreamActual.setInvalid();
            showErrorWindow();
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }else if(upstreamActual.getNumber() <= upstreamRecommended.getNumber()){
            upstreamActual.setInvalid();
            showErrorWindow();
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }else if(biUpstreamActual.getNumber() <= biUpstreamRecommended.getNumber()){
            biUpstreamActual.setInvalid();
            showErrorWindow();
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }else if(biDownstreamActual.getNumber() <= biDownstreamRecommended.getNumber()){
            biDownstreamActual.setInvalid();
            showErrorWindow();
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }
```

Every step we do the same work (call the same method for first object that uses in boolean expression, call `showErrorWindow()` and throw an `Exception`)

What are some good techniques especially using Java 8 to make this code more manageable?

Comment: What are the types of `downstreamActual`,`upstreamActual`,`upstreamRecommended`,... etc? Are they of the same type? Or do they have a common base class? Or a common interface?

Comment: If your code works and you just wish to review it, you may want to ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Eran Yes they are the same type of NumberTextBox

Comment: @fxm I think it's a valid question. Many of the Java 8 questions in SO ask how to convert working Java 7 code to Java 8 code using lambda expressions, Streams, etc... This question is just lacking some details about the types involved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The way you both show an error window and throw an exception looks like lack of proper separation of concerns to me. You should have the calling code catch the `NumberFormatException` and react by showing the error window. Split the business logic from the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, I don't think you need Java 8 constructs.

Just use a method :

```
 public void validate (NumberTextBox actual, NumberTextBox recommended) 
 {
     if(actual.getNumber() <= recommended.getNumber()) {
        actual.setInvalid();
        showErrorWindow();
        throw new NumberFormatException();
     }
 }
```

Then call it 4 times :

```
 validate (downstreamActual,downstreamRecommended);
 validate (upstreamActual,upstreamRecommended);
 ...
```

Since the first one that fails would throw an exception, thus preventing the rest of them from being tested, you don't need the if else-if structure.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the java 8 involvement here, but one thing you could do is create a method for that piece of if-else chain in the following manner:

```
public void handleStreams() throws NumberFormatException {
    if(downstreamActual.getNumber() <= downstreamRecommended.getNumber()) {
        setInvalid(downstreamActual);
    } else if(upstreamActual.getNumber() <= upstreamRecommended.getNumber()) {
        setInvalid(upstreamActual);
    } else if(biUpstreamActual.getNumber() <= biUpstreamRecommended.getNumber()) {
        setInvalid(biUpstreamActual);
    } else if(biDownstreamActual.getNumber() <= biDownstreamRecommended.getNumber()) {
        setInvalid(biDownstreamActual);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    showErrorWindow();
    throw new NumberFormatException();
}

public void setInvalid(MyObject stream) {
    stream.setInvalid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If those streams have a common super class then you can implement this directly in them. In other words if

```
public class DownstreamActual extends CustomStream {
```

then you can add `recommendation` as a variable to the `CustomStream` class

```
public int recommendedValue;
```

and set it when you create the instance.. Then you can create a method which will check the values

```
public void checkRecommendedValue() {
    if(this.getNumber() <= this.recommendedValue){
        this.setInvalid();
        showErrorWindow();
        throw new NumberFormatException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do with java 8 is avoid making a separate method (if that calls to you) and create one right inside your method using the new syntax:

```
BiConsumer<Thing, Thing> check = (actual, recommended) -> {
    if (actual.getNumber() <= recommended.getNumber()) {
        actual.setInvalid();
        showErrorWindow();
        throw new NumberFormatException();
    }
};

check.accept(downstreamActual, downstreamRecommended);
check.accept(upstreamActual, upstreamRecommended);
check.accept(biUpstreamActual, biUpstreamRecommended);
check.accept(biDownstreamActual, biDownstreamRecommended);
```

Comment: This is a good start. Now if you define an `ActualRecommended` data object, and provide a short-named factory (say `ar`), then you could have `Stream.of(ar(downstreamActual,downstreamRecommended), ar(upstreamActual,upssteamRecommended), ...).forEach(ar -> { ...handling code... });`

Comment: Further out, since this looks for just the first invalid instance, it could be refactored into using `findFirst`, then applying the logic to that.

Comment: While this would work I don't really see any advantages over Eran's method. (unless you consider 'look, I used Java 8 stuff!' an advantage.)  Eran's method is as performant and more readable (as the method has a clear name).  This kind of looks like the code-equivalent to object denial :)

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx Personally, I agree with you, but it's a matter of style.  The op asked what options he has to rewrite his method with java 8 and this approach is at least worth considering.